# Modifying Uniform Grid Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, uniformgrid

I am currently using a Uniform Grid to show a number of custom controls.

I have my uniform grid set up with dynamic items like so

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LISTOFOBJECTS}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

With a custom control being used to represent the items.

This is working almost exactly as I want, however some of my controls depending on properties of the item have a maximum width set. This results in the control having large margins because of how Uniform grid works (its in the name really isn't it) is there a straightforward way to overide the layout of the uniform grid to give up this "margin space" to other items that do not have a max width set.

See Picture Below

[image: Image For Clarity]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is. If you give a bit more information about your intended usage maybe people can suggest workarounds using different controls. You could always create your own custom control that works like the uniform grid, but with the changes you need, but I wouldn't say that's straightforward http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/UniformGrid.cs,a4592db73e6521dc

Comment: is there a reason you can't use the regular grid?  it is flexible for situations just like this

Comment: Do you have example how that would  work with an arbitrary number of controls, and without knowing in advance their size